# How can I make a three level Gyroscope, parented object with Align Euler to Vector in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, parent

I'm pretty new to *Geometry Nodes* and I add this idea of a Gyroscope object to follow a reference object (and then make a grid of them).

I'm pretty sure I need to use *Align Euler to Vector* but the subtility is to limit the rotation to one axis per level on the Object (X and then Y and then X again)

I understand how to rotate on only one axis but not contrain/connect one "level" to the other one...

the desired design:
[image: the desired design]

My failed attempt:
[image: my failed attempt]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Unfortunately I don't quite understand your goal. Could you please outline it in more detail? To align the rotations of such a design to an object, you actually only need two axes/objects. If you rotate the outer part and then the inner part, then this surface already points exactly in the direction of the target.

Comment: Hi, 

the goal is to have the center part having his normal align to the reference object, but I would like to do it with GeoNodes and not having to rotate each element,

I managed with " align euler to vector " to have the centered part beiing align with the targeted object, but not the two other levels of the gyroscope, with the difficulty to have them limited to one axys


edit: I send it without finish

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but you don't need three parts for that, two are enough. As soon as you align the outer part on one axis, you only need to align another part on another axis, and the normal points in the direction of the object. Please try to illustrate this more precisely, because I think there is a conceptual error here that should be solved before working with nodes.

Comment: Yes but no ! If I have two elements it can follow left & right and up & down but If this goes above, or under it ,it needs the third rotation

Comment: 2 rotations can orient an axis from any center  to any point on the sphere. The remaining rotation is a spin about the oriented axis..

Comment: Yes you were right I did avance on the object and two level is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here lies in the cascading of the rotations, which the node `Align Euler to Vector` creates for you.

How you choose the options of this node depends very much on how your objects are aligned and on which axes they rotate.

A little trial and error helps here.

In my example (since you didn't share your blend file) I just use three objects, instantiate them on a grid and rotate them individually:

[image]

Of course you can also combine all objects, mark them with `Capture Attribute`, realize them as a mesh after instantiation and move/rotate the points individually, but that would be a lot more work.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much I will study your blend file to understand exactly all the step but this what I was looking for :